Best way do perform batching (algorithm)
Note: This is more of a algorithm/strategy question then coding...
I am working on a project where users carry out activities as part of duties.
Each Duty is collection of activities list (one or more) and one duty gets assigned to more than 1 user.
i.e.

User to Duties has multiplicity of many to many.
Duties to activities has multiplicity of 1 to many

Each duty (along with activities) is time bound and should be performed on specific day. There are different (business) rules that decides whether a specfic user can be assigned to duty or not. We call it RuleValidations, these are executed when assiging the duty OR when there is a change in duty or user (user's other data - licenses, training and a lot more).
When validating a duty, it requires all assignments (users who are going to carry out the duty together) and their related data (licences, training and more roughly data from 7 tables).
We have a nightly operation (integration with external party) where it sends duty and user updates in bulk forcing us to perform RuleValidation for almost all duties.
Currently the operation takes 15min and expectation is to finish it within 30 sec.
Proposed solutions:
Instead of validating all duties in one transaction,

batch duties in small batches and validate each batches separately
batch users in small batches and validate assigned duties separately

The real problem:

I cannot batch the duties by user since it can introduce concurrency problem. i.e. one duty will start validating into different batches causing concurrency problem when saving result into database.
I can batch the duties (by their Ids into smaller batches) but it is not performant since one user's data is being read multiple times in different batches. (This is the main root cause of slownessness since read of 2000 users data (from 7 tables) takes 20sec.

I am looking at options to fix this in a way that it won't introduce concurrency problem and at the same time is performant.

"one duty will start validating into different batches causing concurrency problem when saving result into database." - Please explain what you mean by this. I don't see how discussing concurrency is relevant at all here...

Say you have a duty 'a' that because of batching starts validating into two batches (running in parallel), the result of validation for duty 'a' will cause concurrency in database... I will endup storing duplicate results.

"(This is the main root cause of slownessness since read of 2000 users data (from 7 tables) takes 20sec." - This sounds like your database is missing indexes or similar more than anything else. Your concern about "user's data is being read multiple times" is not something I consider a real problem.
